# Set HTTP REFERRER on HTTPS to HTTPS site

Tags: php, javascript, html, .net

Can someone please tell me how to avoid http REFERRER url. I have a html form and i want to post the form using Javascript. is it possible to set REFERRER url as NULL.
Here is the code please let me know if this is possible or you have any alternative
Appreciate your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<form id="l" method="post" action="https://www.test.com">');
document.write('<input type="hidden" id="e" name="email">');
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="pass" id="p"></form>');

function g(x){

  return document.getElementById(x);
}

g('e').value='username';
g('p').value="password";
g('l').submit();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's so bad about having a referer URL?

Comment: I do understand its useful and important but i need to realize this so want to know if i can do it

Comment: messing with browser set headers, that sure sounds legit ;)

Comment: to mark as answer it is not possible i'll mark that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Referer` header is something the browser sends to the Server. You cannot change it since browsers do not provide a javascript api to change it.

The browser sends the location.href of the window object. If you change it to something else like location.href = "http://www.google.com"  the browser will navigate away from your page to http://www.google.com

Comment: Can you please tell me on what basis it sends the Referrer url. Is it like if its https to https redirection it will not set that?